# Small error in html/CSS formatting to freeze first column in PHP generated SQL tables

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, freeze

I have a niggling error that no one seems to be able to fix but I'm sure it is very simple and possibly CSS related.

I wish for the first column (that is the usernames) to be frozen/fixed in order for the user to scroll through the other columns (the tests, of which there are many).

This now works, but the positioning of the username is out of synch with the rest of the table.

It looks like this:

[image]

and it should look like:

[image]

PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php  }elseif(isset($_POST['quiz']) && $_POST['quiz'] == "non" && $err == ""){ ?>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="table">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="3%"></td>
                        <?php
                            $all_quizes = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quizes ORDER BY FIELD(quiz_level, 'Beginner','Intermediate','Advanced'),quiz_name ASC");
                            $quizes = array();
                            while($my_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($all_quizes)){
                                array_push($quizes,$my_rows);
                            }
                            foreach($all_quizes as $record){
                        ?>

                        <th width="30%"><?php echo $record['quiz_name']; ?></th>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach(@$result as $record){?>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="headcol"><?php echo $record["username"];?></td>
                            <?php
                            $counter=0;
                            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                            while(mysqli_num_rows($all_quizes) > $counter){
                                $current_td = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quiz_takers WHERE username='".$record["username"]."' AND quiz_id=".$quizes[$counter][0]." ORDER BY marks DESC");
                                $td = mysqli_fetch_array($current_td);

                                if($td['percentage'] == null){

                                    echo "<td> ?</td>";
                                }else{
                                    if(intval($td["percentage"]) >= 0 && intval($td["percentage"]) <= 30){
                                        $color = 'red';
                                    }elseif(intval($td["percentage"]) > 30 && intval($td["percentage"]) <= 70){
                                        $color = '#ffbf00';
                                    }elseif(intval($td["percentage"]) <= 30){

                                    }else{
                                        $color = 'green';
                                    }
                                    echo "<td style='color:".$color."'>".round($td["percentage"],2)."%</td>";

                                }

                                $counter++;
                            }
                            /*foreach($current_td as $td){
                                echo $counter." ".$td['username'] . " - ".$quizes[$counter]['3']."<br>";
                                if($quizes[$counter]['0'] == $td['quiz_id']){
                            ?>
                            <td><?php echo $td["percentage"];?></td>
                            <?php  } $counter++;}*/ ?>
                    </tr>
                        <?php  } ?>


                    </tbody>


                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**The current css is:**

```
<style>



.headcol {

  position:absolute;
  height:100px;

  width: 5em;
  left: -10;


  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 5em;

  padding: 0;

  top: 2;
  border-top-width: -2px;
  /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top: -90px;
  /*compensate for top border*/
}



</style>
```

Could someone please suggest a solution or fix?

Comment: I'd be tempted to use two tables - one for the usernames and the other for other data

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to post a two table solution using my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue coming from the first column of the first heading row, which you defined the width of 3%. This width should equal to the width of `.headcol`

Something like this

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td width="5em"></td> //equal to the width of .headcol
```

Besides, you may need to adjust your CSS of .headcol so it can be aligned better, maybe put `left: 0;`

Comment: Hi - just tried this, both things you suggested, but there was no change at all. Any other ideas?! Note the issue isn't the width of the head-col, but the positioning. It is floating in the middle, rather than being fixed on the left, aligned with the other columns and rows in the table

Comment: I mean to put `left: 0;`, sorry for answer above!

Comment: I just made this https://codepen.io/huuvan20/pen/gvqjBZ.
Basically, I change the `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` which is better. Please play around to match your works.

Comment: left:0; or even left:-10 only moves it ever so slightly to the left. still no difference :(

Comment: Huu Van Tran- thank you, yes I have a similar thing done too, see this: http://www.teachingcomputing.com/testandtrack_tc/testingpage.php ,,,which achieves what you have done, but I need to integrate it with my existing code (that is the php which generates the row etc).

Comment: Hm - also I assume if I use table it will overwrite all the other tables used in the page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166036/discussion-between-misscomputing-and-huuvan-tran).